# my contact form mails me blank values when clicked send

Tags: php, html, contacts, contact-form

When this form gets submitted I receive an email which have all the values as blank please help me.

This is my html file in which I am accepting name, email, and message as input.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="contact.php" >
    <fieldset>
        <label><input type="text" value="Name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Name' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><input type="text" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><textarea onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}">Message</textarea></label><br>
        <<a href="#" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Send</a></div>
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```

php file:

in php file I want to email all the details on id jay44556677@gmail.com.

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['Name'];
$field_email = $_POST['Email'];
$field_message = $_POST['Message'];

$mail_to = 'jay44556677@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contacts.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please try again.');
        window.location = 'contacts.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every input form element should have name field otherwise it will send blank value.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="contact.php" >
                  <fieldset>
                    <label><input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Name' ) this.value=''"></label>
                    <label><input type="text" name="Email" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''"></label>
                    <label><textarea name="Message" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}">Message</textarea></label><br>
                    <<a href="#" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Send</a></div>
                  </fieldset>  
                </form>
```

Comment: btw one more question in the below href.. what value should i give?

Comment: then what may be the reason for the blank values?

Comment: put print_r($_POST); in contact.php and you will get right value So you need to debug your mail function.

Comment: hey i got it :) i rectified my mistake..:)

Answer (score 3):

You never specify `name=`s for your form elements, so the values never get submitted to your server.

```
<input type="text" value="Name" ...
<input type="text" value="Email" ...
```

need to have a name field added:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" ...
<input type="text" name="Email" value="Email" ...
```

Comment: i am sorry.. my error meant that i am still getting the blank values..
and one more question in the below href.. what value should i give or to keep it blank?

<a href="#" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Send</a>

Comment: so now what should i do to avoid blank values that i am getting while emailed..?